# Drones and Model Aircraft Site proposal

Tags: discussion

I'm the creator of the ["Drones and Model Aircraft" SE site proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/123448/drones-and-model-aircraft?referrer=ZmE4YWM1ZWU2ZjY5MWQwMWRmOTA1OTc2ZjkxZjAxM2ZlODdhOGJlNGVjYjFhZjAwZTFjNWEyYjBhYjk2NDY4OLDMyKDmFz1uUizHMJ7iBT-Kq7o5vD1yZrURKVuvgOW50). Aside from reaching the requirement for >100 committers with >200 reputation, we are doing very well.

[image]

Since our communities have a ***lot*** in common with all of the 3D printing I know takes place in the model aircraft and drone flying hobbies, I'm hoping to be able to convince some 3DPrinting.Meta users to commit to our proposal.

As I mention in [this Area51.Meta post](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29987/165459):

> The problem arises from the fact that since this community is fairly different in scope and intended audience in comparison to most other existing SE sites, we have only been able to recruit a little less than half of the required supporters with >200 reputation across the Stack Exchange platform.

Comment: Our Meta is tiny...

Comment: Yeah it might be, but unfortunately @Trish, every little bit helps our case here... Area51 is unfortunately understaffed at this time.

Comment: Basically, your question could be seen as an advertisement. So instead of focus on getting enough people to backup your proposal, you could go a little more in detail how *3DPrinting* and *Drones and Model Aircraft* are not overlapping. This still gets your attraction while discussing overlap. E.g. design of servo mounts could be posted at your site, while printing issues with supports or filament specific questions fit better here.